# KDE - move app window between monitors via keyboard

Tags: kde, window-manager

I'm looking for a utility that moves app windows between multiple monitors in KDE.

Answer (score 35):

KDE supports it (at least in version 4.8), but the relevant shortcuts are disabled by default.

To enable them, open `systemsettings` and browse to Common Appearance and Behavior -> Shortcuts and Gestures -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts. Select `KWin` under "KDE component", and search for `window to`. You will see several "Window to Screen n" and "Window to Next Screen" actions. Since you probably only have a 2 or 3 screens, it's probably simplest to create a  shortcut for "Window to Next Screen" only (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>).

Comment: Under kubuntu 16.04, if you do not have a kwin component, check under the "System Settings" component.

Answer (score 15):

In even more recent KDE versions (System Settings 5.14.5, KDE 5.53.0):

`System Settings` → `Shortcuts` → `KWin` → `Window to next screen` (or similar)

The functionality works extremely well and can also be used to move full-screen presentation windows to the correct screen if an application goes full screen on the wrong output.

Answer (score 5):

In KDE 5.x (Plasma):

`System Settings` → `Shortcuts` → `Global Shortcuts` → `Settings` → `Pack […] Window […]`

Comment: Packing a Window is actually a slightly different activity, which first puts the window to one side of your current screen. "Window to Next Screen" seems closer to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

in Fedora with KDE spin I know it defaults to SuperKey+Shift+left or right arrow keys.

To Change
System Setting > Workspace > Shortcuts > Kwin > find Window to Prev/Next Screen or Window To Screen X